# How to make DeskBands work on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64, taskbar, deskband

I'm going to create an application (C#), which has its DeskBand on the Windows TaskBar. I've found one complete [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx) program, which does this, but I didn't manage to successfully install (add to Toolbars menu on the taskbar) it. I think, it's because my Windows is x64, there are no other visible reasons...

So, my question is how to create and add a deskband to Windows 7 x64 taskbar?

Comment: Why do you think 64 bit is the issue?

Comment: Because I cant see any other reasons for it not to work, and google shows, that there exist some problems with deskbands on x64 windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft, [Deskbands are not recommended for Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446.aspx#deskbands), although they still work.  Also keep in mind that Microsoft requires that [Deskbands support Aero on Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460%28VS.85%29.aspx#deskbands) via IDeskband2 Interface, rather than IDeskband.  Also, Micorosft has officially said that [IDeskBand2 may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of the operating system or product.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762064%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Finally, be very careful about [creating shell extensions in managed code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx).

Comment: AFAIK, the main problem with shell extensions in managed code doesnt exist with 4 NET version - it allows running more than one CLR version per process.

So, I've heard Microsoft opinion about Deskbands in Windows 7+, but what replacement do they offer?

Comment: No, I think you are confusing being able to target multiple versions of the framework with being able to run different versions.  I have not heard of the capability you speak of.  The alternative is to use thumbnails and thumbnail toolbars.

Comment: Hm... Really, thumbnails seem to be the only alternative and they have almost all needed features.

Comment: It would be oxymoron from Microsoft to remove support for Deskbands, there is no alternative. The thumbnail toolbar is not visible at one glance and cannot be moved to other end of the taskbar. (I have a need for project timer in Deskband and putting it to thumbnail would be just counterproductive)

Comment: @Ciantic - Microsoft has already deprecated them.  They can disappear at any time, even in a service pack.  Don't depend on them being there.  Just because you find them indepsepensible doesn't mean that Microsoft feels the same.  thumbnails are MS's replacement.