# How to add content to windows taskbar

Tags: c#, windows, taskbar

I have been trying to figure out, for some time, how to add content to the taskbar next to the clock.  You can see examples of this in NetSpeedMonitor or NetWorx.  I am a noob to taskbar but I cannot find anything no matter how hard I look.  I am not interested in ThumbButtonInfo or NotifyIcon.  Here are a a couple examples of content in the taskbar(incase I'm not saying this right).  I would like so be able to do something similar to the first one:

[image: NetSpeedMonitor has text in the taskbar]

[image: NetWorx]

Thank you,
 Rymn

Comment: It's called a "DeskBand": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345253/display-a-complete-application-in-windows-7-taskbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example in codeproject showing E[xtending Explorer with Band Objects using .NET and Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and)

> Build a Release version of BandObjectLib and register it in the Global
>   Assembly Cache. The easiest way to do this is to open
>   BandObjectLib.sln in Visual Studio, set the active configuration to
>   Release and select 'Rebuild Solution' from the 'Build' menu. The
>   second project in the solution - RegisterLib - is a C++ utility
>   project that performs the 'gacutil /if BandObjectLib.dll' command that
>   puts assembly into GAC.
>
> As you probably already know, Band Objects are COM components. And for
>   the .NET framework to find an assembly that implements a COM component
>   it must be either be registered in the GAC or located in the directory
>   of the client application. There are two possible client applications
>   for Band Objects - explorer.exe and iexplorer.exe. Explorer is located
>   in the windows directory and IE somewhere inside 'Program Files'. So
>   GAC is actually the only one option in this case. Thus .NET assemblies
>   that implement Band Objects should be registered in GAC and all
>   libraries they depend on - like BandObjectLib.dll - should also be
>   there.
>
> Assemblies in the GAC must have strong names and thus key pairs are
>   required. I have provided the BandObjects.snk file with a key pair but
>   I encourage you to replace it with your own. See the sn.exe tool for
>   more details.
>
> Create a new Windows Control Library project and call it SampleBars.
>   We are going to rely on the base functionality of BandObjectLib so we
>   have to add a reference to BandObjectLib\Relase\bin\BandObjectLib.dll.
>   As we are developing a 'Hello World Bar', rename UserControl1.cs and
>   the UserControl1 class inside it appropriately - into HelloWolrdBar.cs
>   and HelloWorldBar. Also put the following lines at the beginning of
>   HelloWorldBar.cs:
>
> ```
> using BandObjectLib;
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
> ```
>
> Make HelloWorldBar class inherit BandObject instead of
>   System.Windows.Forms.UserControl. As I mentioned earlier, Band Objects
>   are COM components so we should use the Guid attribute. Use
>   guidgen.exe to generate your unique GUID or you can use the one I have
>   generated for you:
>
> ```
> [Guid("AE07101B-46D4-4a98-AF68-0333EA26E113")]
> ```
>
> We also have to sign our assembly with a strong name. You can do this
>   by putting the following line into AssemblyInfo.cs file:
>
> ```
> [assembly: AssemblyKeyFile(@"..\..\..\BandObjects.snk")]
> ```
>
> Now its time to decide what kind of Band Object we want to develop.
>   Lets make it an Explorer Toolbar as well as a Horizontal Explorer Bar
>   (also known as a Browser Communication Band). All we need to do to
>   implement this decision is to add custom BandObject attribute to our
>   HelloWorldBar class:
>
> ```
> [Guid("AE07101B-46D4-4a98-AF68-0333EA26E113")]
> [BandObject("Hello World Bar",
> BandObjectStyle.Horizontal | BandObjectStyle.ExplorerToolbar,
> HelpText = "Shows bar that says hello.")]
> public class HelloWorldBar : BandObject
> { ...
> ```
>
> That's enough to make our control available through 'View->Explorer
>   Bars' and 'View->Toolbars' explorer menus. It also takes care of menu
>   item text - "Hello World Bar", and hen the menu item is highlighted
>   status bar displays "Shows bar that says hello.". Don't you like
>   declarative programming and custom attributes?
>
> Now it is time to open HelloWorldBar.cs in the Visual Studio Designer
>   and put some controls on it. Although in my version of HelloWorldBar I
>   decided to put a single button with 'Say Hello' caption on it you are
>   free to do something more personalized. I made the size of the button
>   equal to the size of the control's client area and also set its Anchor
>   property to the combination of all possible styles - 'Top, Bottom,
>   Left, Right'. The background color is 'HotTrack' and ForeColor is
>   'Info'.
>
> The BandObject control has several properties specific to the Band
>   Objects (and so classes derived from it) - Title , MinSize, MaxSize
>   and IntegralSize. I set Title for HelloWorldBar to "Hello Bar" and
>   both MinSize and Size to '150, 24'. Oh, and in button's On Click event
>   handler I put code that displays a message box. This is what my final
>   code looks like (and most of it was generated by VS.Net):
>
> ```
> using System;
> using System.ComponentModel;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> using BandObjectLib;
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
>
> namespace SampleBars
> {
>     [Guid("AE07101B-46D4-4a98-AF68-0333EA26E113")]
>     [BandObject("Hello World Bar", BandObjectStyle.Horizontal 
>          | BandObjectStyle.ExplorerToolbar, HelpText = "Shows bar that says hello.")]
>     public class HelloWorldBar : BandObject
>     {
>         private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
>         private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;
>
>         public HelloWorldBar()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }
>
>         protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
>         {
>             if( disposing )
>             {
>                 if( components != null )
>                     components.Dispose();
>             }
>             base.Dispose( disposing );
>         }
>
>         #region Component Designer generated code
>         private void InitializeComponent()
>         {
>             this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
>             this.SuspendLayout();
>             // 
>             // button1
>             // 
>             this.button1.Anchor = (((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top 
>                 | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
>                 | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
>                 | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right);
>             this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
>             this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Info;
>             this.button1.Name = "button1";
>             this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 24);
>             this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
>             this.button1.Text = "Say Hello";
>             this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
>             // 
>             // HelloWorldBar
>             // 
>             this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.button1 });
>             this.MinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 24);
>             this.Name = "HelloWorldBar";
>             this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 24);
>             this.Title = "Hello Bar";
>             this.ResumeLayout(false);
>
>         }
>         #endregion
>
>         private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
>         {
>             MessageBox.Show("Hello, World!");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Ok, now we are ready to build SampleBars.dll but its not enough to see
>   it in explorer yet. We have to put our assembly into the GAC as well
>   as register it as a COM server. There are tools - gacutil.exe and
>   regasm.exe that do just this. The C++ utility project named Register
>   in my version of the SampleBars solution liberates me from using these
>   tools manually. It has no files in it, just the following post-build
>   command (debug version):
>
> ```
> cd $(ProjectDir)..\bin\Debug
> gacutil /if SampleBars.dll
> regasm SampleBars.dll
> ```
>
> Of cause you have to make sure that Register project is the last one
>   to be built in the solution using Project Dependencies / Build Order.
>
> After building the solution, and executing the gacutil and regasm
>   commands, we are finally ready to start Explorer and see our toolbar
>   and explorer bar. And if you did everything right you should be able
>   to see something like the picture at the top of the article. On this
>   picture you can also see how HelloWorldBar looks in the Windows
>   Taskbar. To achieve this all you need to do is to modify BandObject
>   attribute adding the BandObjectStyle.TaskbarToolBar flag.

---

Also you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5557765/2263683)

> According to Microsoft, [Deskbands are not recommended for Windows
>   7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446.aspx#deskbands), although they still work.  Also keep in mind that Microsoft
>   requires that [Deskbands support Aero on Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378460%28VS.85%29.aspx#deskbands) via IDeskband2
>   Interface, rather than IDeskband.  Also, Micorosft has officially said
>   that [IDeskBand2 may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions
>   of the operating system or product.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762064%28VS.85%29.aspx)
>
> Finally, be very careful about [creating shell extensions in managed
>   code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx).